# Loop through <li> using javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

**Note: This is a mixture of Php, Javascript and html.**

I have a code below

```
            <div class="chat-sidebar-list-wrapper pt-2">
                <h6 class="px-2 pt-2 pb-25 mb-0">MAIDS</h6>
                <ul class="chat-sidebar-list  maid-list-wrapper">
                <?php
                    foreach($all_maids as $all_maid){
                        ?>
                    <!-- displaying looped results in <li> using php foreach method-->
                    <li id="<?php echo $all_maid->id?>" class="bingo">
                     <input type="hidden" id="hidden_receiver_id" name="hidden_receiver_id" value="<?php echo $all_maid->id?>"/>
                        <div class="d-flex align-items-center">
                            <div class="avatar m-0 mr-50"><img src="<?php echo base_url('uploads/'); ?>images/<?php echo get_user_image($all_maid->id)?>" height="36" width="36" alt="sidebar user image">
                                <span class="avatar-status-busy"></span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="chat-sidebar-name">
                                <h6 class="mb-0 maid-names"><?php echo $all_maid->first_name. "" . $all_maid->last_name ?></h6><span class="text-muted">Maid</span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <?php } ?>
                </ul>
              .......
            </div>
```

What i want is, when you click on each `<li>` items, you should be able to get the ID from the input tag                          `<input type="hidden" id="hidden_receiver_id" name="hidden_receiver_id" value="<?php echo $all_maid->id?>"/>`.

So how can i loop the `<li>` items and get each of it IDs from the input tag?

I tried something below but not working

```
        var listItems = $(".maid-list-wrapper li");
        listItems.each(function(idx, li) {
            //var id = $(li).text();
            alert($("li.bingo").find("input#hidden_receiver_id").text());
        });
```

Comment: Generating many elements with same `id` attribute in the loop will cause errors. `id` **must** be unique at whole page, they cannot repeat. `<input type="hidden" id="hidden_receiver_id"`

Comment: @biesior The divs contains some data to be shown, so obviously it will not cause error. Please read the question and look at the code well.

Comment: @biesior This is a chat application. So to send chat to another user, you must have their ID. so each users ID is saved in the hidden input tag.

Comment: @ObotErnest What you are being told is correct. Element IDs are unique by definition. Like a building address; if 10 places have same address how can you send mail to a single one?

Comment: In your `each` use `$(this).find...` and use common class name instead of repeating id

Comment: @charlietfl Can you give me example from my code?

Comment: `alert($(this).find("input[type='hidden']").val());` Note you need `val()` not `text()` for form controls

Comment: @charlietfl Regard man! i was even able to get each users name by twaeking your code `console.log($(this).find("h6.maid-names").text());`

Comment: i called th code in the onclick  `$('.maid-list-wrapper li').click(function() {}`

Comment: Now change that repeating id on the hidden input and give it a class name instead for a more informative selector

Comment: @charlietfl Thanks man! i added `class="hidden_receiver_id"` and wrote the code as `console.log($(this).find("input.hidden_receiver_id").val());`

Comment: @charlietfl. Thanks everyone for your effort. Let's code on

Comment: There you go...much better!

Comment: @charlietfl I just posted the answer so anyone with this issue might solve it quickly

Comment: @charlietfl Vote it as useful pls

Comment: @ObotErnest it will rise `duplicate id reference` error ;) simplest solution is making id unique in each loops iteration i.e. by adding an unique id of item to it `<input type="hidden" id="hidden_receiver_id_<?php echo $all_maid->id?>" name="hidden_receiver_id" value="<?php echo $all_maid->id?>"/>`

Comment: @biesior Thanks man! i will update my code

Comment: Your question would probably be more useful to future readers, if you made your example more minimal, e.g. remove unnecessary classes and elements and instead of php you could simply show what that expands to (not all elements but some)

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery

```
var items = $(".chat-sidebar-list li");
items.each(function(id, li) {
    var OneItem = $(li);
    // and the rest of your code.OneItem is an object here
});
```

Comment: I didn't just mean looping through each <li> item, i mean also getting the value of each hidden html input tag.

Comment: ` <input type="hidden" id="hidden_receiver_id" name="hidden_receiver_id" value="<?php echo $all_maid->id?>"/>`. So each <li> item has a unique ID assigned to its hidden input tag.

Comment: try to console.log(OneItem),it will show you an object,so you can pick the data you want to use

Comment: Thanks for your support. I was able to solve it. but not your own code but the other way round. I just posted the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is

i added `class="hidden_receiver_id"` to  `<input type="hidden" id="hidden_receiver_id" class="hidden_receiver_id" name="hidden_receiver_id" value="<?php echo $all_maid->id?>"/>`

```
        $('.maid-list-wrapper li').click(function() {
            //name of each user
            console.log($(this).find("h6.maid-names").text());

             //ID of each user
            //alert($(this).find("input[type='hidden']").val());
            console.log($(this).find("input.hidden_receiver_id").val()) 
        });
```